# moving files into different directories based on their names matching with another file

Tags: shell, file-management

I have a folder with ~6000 files (some of the are .txt and some .pdf files) and I am trying to organize them in different folders. folder looks like this:

```
$ ls ./res-defaults    
ML3020T1--ML3020N_chr6-209980-34769899-LOH_clusters.pdf
ML3020T1--ML3020N_chrom_clust_freqs.txt
ML3020T1--ML3020N_cluster_summary.txt
ML3020T1--ML3020N_mol_time_estimate.pdf
HTMCP-01-01-00451-01A-01D--HTMCP-01-01-00451-11B-01D_boots.txt

....
```

I have then another file which is a metadata file

```
$ head meta.data
bam TRUE    81-52884    81-52884T   tumour  grch37  genome  A01423  DL_M    
bam TRUE    06-30342    ML3020T1    tumour  grch37  genome  A43002  ML_K        
bam TRUE    10-24757    10-24757T   tumour  grch37  genome  A61218  CL_GC
bam TRUE    HTMCP-01-01-00451   HTMCP-01-01-00451-01A-01D   tumour  grch37  genome  A71785  DL_HTMCP
    ....
```

The strings **"before"** the **"--"** in file names in the res-defaults folder matche with the column 4 in the metadata file.

I want create folders according to the column 9 in the metadata and move files in the res-default to the directory that column 4 in meta data matche with characters before "--".

I am expecting outputs like this

```
$ ls ./ML_K
ML3020T1--ML3020N_chr6-209980-34769899-LOH_clusters.pdf
ML3020T1--ML3020N_chrom_clust_freqs.txt
ML3020T1--ML3020N_cluster_summary.txt
ML3020T1--ML3020N_mol_time_estimate.pdf
```

and

```
$ ls./DL_HTMCP
HTMCP-01-01-00451-01A-01D--HTMCP-01-01-00451-11B-01D_boots.txt
```

I honestly do not know how to do that with bash shell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to print the 4th and 9th fields:

```
$ awk '{print $4,$9}' meta.data
81-52884T DL_M
ML3020T1 ML_K
10-24757T CL_GC
HTMCP-01-01-00451-01A-01D DL_HTMCP
```

Next, pass that to `read` and assign each field to a variable. Then, create the target directories (use `mkdir -p` so that it won't complain if the directorty already exists), and move any file names starting with the prefix (4th field) into the directory name given in the 9th field:

```
awk '{print $4,$9}' meta.data | 
    while read prefix dirname; do 
        mkdir -p -- "$dirname" && mv -- "$prefix"* "$dirname"; 
    done
```